# I want Java code to convert word file (doc file having text, images, tables etc. ) into pdf file.

Tags: java, itext

I have added all the necessary jar files including `itextpdf-5.1.0.jar` but still it gives errors.. 
please refer below code.
I searched it on net but it's not working.

It gives error while importing

```
com.lowagie.text.Document; 
com.lowagie.text.Paragraph; 
com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
```

Don't understand what is going wrong. I added latest version of `iText jar` file but not getting the solution.

please give me correct solution or code.
please mention it stepwise.
because I'm doing this first time...

```
    import com.lowagie.text.Document;   
    import com.lowagie.text.Paragraph;    
    import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;    
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;    
    public class Doc2Pdf2 {    
        /**
         * This method is used to convert the given file to a PDF format
         * 
         * @param inputFile
         *            - Name and the path of the file
         * @param outputFile
         *            - Name and the path where the PDF file to be saved
         * @param isPictureFile
         */
        private void createPdf(String inputFile, String outputFile,
                boolean isPictureFile) {
            Document pdfDocument = new Document();
            String pdfFilePath = outputFile;
            try {
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                        pdfFilePath);
                PdfWriter writer = null;
                writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfDocument, fileOutputStream);
                writer.open();
                pdfDocument.open();    
                if (isPictureFile) {                    pdfDocument.add(com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance(inputFile));
                } else {
                    File file = new File(inputFile);
                    pdfDocument.add(new Paragraph(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
                            .readFileToString(file)));
                }
                pdfDocument.close();
                writer.close();
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                System.out.println("Document Exception!" + exception);
            }
        }    
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            PDFConversion pdfConversion = new PDFConversion();
            pdfConversion.createPdf("C:/demo.doc", "C:/demopdf.pdf", true);    
        }    
    }
```

Comment: plz, bt, wat's, bcz, frst. Dear god man.

Comment: Please take a look at the code formatting - help us help you by ensuring the code is readable and properly formatted (including removing the extraneous blank lines (1 blank line is enough), and indentation).

Comment: When i was learning pdf creation using iText then i [refer this article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaPDF/article.html).It is very good article and step by step solution.

Comment: Mr. Sean F,
Please try to give the solution instead of finding the shortforms.

Comment: Hi Greg Kopff,
This is my first question on this site. the code is properly formatted. I submitted the code in proper format but it's not looking readable so I included extraneous blank lines..

Comment: The problem is something to do with your importing of jar files. It's nothing to do with your written code. From the info that you given, it's hard to tell what is wrong. It might be small un-noticed mistake.

Comment: 'It gives errors' is not a problem description.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a version of iText that is higher than 5 (with packages `com.itextpdf`), yet you are importing classes from packages `com.lowagie` (yes, that's my name; I'm the original author of iText) that only exist in versions of iText predating iText 5. Hence it is normal that the classes you're using aren't found. You should replace `com.lowagie` with `com.itextpdf`.

By the way: the title of your question doesn't match the question because iText doesn't convert Word documents to PDF.

Comment: yes i knw iText doesn't convert Word documents to PDF.
with the help of POI libraries i am reading doc file and at the same time i am writing those contents into the PDF file.

After a long time I succeeded but now bothering abt images..

Comment: I don't know what your comment about images is about. Your com.lowagie vs com.itextpdf problem should now be fixed, so please accept the answer that fixed the problem. Create a new question if you have a new problem.

Comment: Ok sir.
actualy my task was to convert doc file into pdf file..
initialy i got errors while importing com.lowagie..But that problem get solved yesterday...

and Sir I have created the new question...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740361/how-to-read-images-from-worddoc-file-and-add-it-to-pdf-file

Comment: @BrunoLowagie hello i have did all the steps which are given here but still i am getting an error  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 org.apache cannot be resolved

Comment: `org.apache` cannot be resolved means that you're trying to use Apache software. I see that you're using `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils`. Did you include the correct Apache Commons jars into your CLASSPATH?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Yes i have included

Comment: @BrunoLowagie and also i am not using the apache software

Comment: Er... Your compiler tells you that you are using Apache software, yet you are telling me that you are not using Apache software. Either your compiler is wrong or you are wrong. As I don't know you, I trust your compiler more (moreover because you first admit that you included Apache Commons and subsequently deny using it). Bottom line: you are missing an import somewhere or you are trying to run code that looks for a class you haven't compiled yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the latest jar in the java build path. Check your projects build path and make sure the jar is present there. Do a clean build and clean publish and it should work. If not then you can even try to directly paste the jar in your projects deployment location (LIB folder).

Answer (score 0):

you can go through tutorials of how to write data into pdf

[Generate Pdf](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-javapdf/)

[creating pdf](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaPDF/article.html)

[create pdf sample hello program](http://www.roseindia.net/java/itext/HelloWordPDF.shtml)

and to read doc file Apache Tika is best :

have a look to read doc file using apache tika in java:

i am reading content from doc file and writing into text file but after learn you can write data into pdf .

```
public class Tikaconvrt {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException
    {
        Tikaconvrt tc=new Tikaconvrt();


        File Re_F = new File("/home/rahul/Documents/212/ANIR.docx");

        String F_Name=Re_F.getName();
        int eof=F_Name.lastIndexOf('.');
        F_Name=F_Name.substring(0, eof); 

        String s1 = tc.contentEx(Re_F);
        tc.files(s1, F_Name);
        }


    public String contentEx(File f) throws IOException, SAXException,
            TikaException {

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);

        Parser ps = new AutoDetectParser();

        BodyContentHandler bch = new BodyContentHandler();
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        ps.parse(is, bch, metadata, new ParseContext());

        return bch.toString();
    }

    public void files(String st,String fname) throws IOException {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/home/rahul/Documents/txt/"+fname+".txt",
                true);
        BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bufferWritter.write(st + "\n");
        bufferWritter.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: but my doc file contains images and tables also.
and whenever i am trying to write images into pdf it gives error..
I think something is wrong with jar file.

i need iText correct jar file which wil handle this properly.
but not found yet..