# How to Read images from word(DOC) file and add it to pdf file?

Tags: java, apache-poi, itext

I have a doc file that contains text,images etc etc.

Now I want to read that doc file and write those contents into pdf file. My DOC file and newly generated PDF file has to be same.

I repeat, My DOC file contains ( "images as well as text" data ).

If anyone have this code please help me out.

Thank you so much for your time..

Comment: What you have tried yet?

Comment: These are two questions: (1) how to get the image using POI, and (2) how to create an Image using iText. As (2) is a no-brainer, I suggest that you remove the iText tag from your question.

Comment: K sir. I have changed my question. Now give me the solution.

Comment: Hi vimal,

Right now I can read doc file having only text data and I can easily add that text data into another pdf file.

Bt my primary requirement is to read entire doc file having Text, Images, Tables etc etc

but i dnt know how to read images and text data at a time and add these data into PDF file..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get all the images from your document.

```
HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);// fs is the object of POIFSFileSystem 
Range range = doc.getRange();
PicturesTable pt = doc.getPicturesTable();
List<Picture> listPic = pt.getAllPictures();
Picture pic = listPic.get(0);// iterate listPic upto its size to get images
byte[] picArr = pic.getContent();
```

Comment: Thanx Rahul...Bt I dnt want to get images and text separately.

Comment: You can iterate through paragraph and if you get any Special Charater or not an instance of CharacterRun then get image from listPic from that position. But it assumes that your file does not contains any other special characters.